# Python datetime different from iPhone date

Tags: iphone, python, objective-c, google-app-engine

In Google App Engine, I have a datetime property with `(auto_now_add=True)`. In Objective-C on my iPhone, getting the current time gets me `2012-04-17 6:55:01` while on Python the `auto_now_add` got me `2012-04-17 11:55:01`.

`6:55` is my local time, and I'm not sure what time zone or format the Python date is in. How do I get both to match, either through Python or through Objective-C?

**Edit:** So apparently the Python date is in UTC format. But what format is my iPhone date in? I thought `[NSDate date]` is also in UTC? Why am I getting different results?

**Edit 2:** Ok got it. Needed to do this in Objective-C

```
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the app engine always works in UTC time, your phone is probably in a different timezone.

> The runtime's TZ environment variable is set to UTC, and can't be changed. Timestamps returned by e.g. time.time() and datetime.datetime.now() will always be in UTC. Similarly, datetime properties in the datastore will always be stored and returned as UTC.
>
> You can change the time zone of a datetime in memory with the astimezone() method.

[Source](http://timezones.appspot.com/)